# Mysql Join get multiple rows even if one of them not meet search condition

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to get multiple rows with mysql join but if one of the rows doesn't meet the search condition didn't get it.
example :

I have a products table and orders table and order_products table
when someone order like 2 products I insert the order information in the order table and insert every product with its quantity in order_products table with order id

this is the schema I have

products table

```
| id | title  |
---------------
| 1  |   p1   |
| 2  |   p2   |
| 3  |   p3   |
| 4  |   p4   |
```

Orders table

```
| id | client |
---------------
| 1  |   c1   |
| 2  |   c2   |
| 3  |   c3   |
```

order_products table

```
| id | order_id| product_id |
-----------------------------
| 1  |   1     |   1        |
| 2  |   1     |   2        |
| 3  |   2     |   4        |
| 4  |   3     |   3        |
```

my query is

```
SELECT `orders`.*, GROUP_CONCAT(`products`.`title` SEPARATOR ' ') AS products FROM `orders` LEFT JOIN `order_products` ON `order_products`.`order_id` = `orders`.`id` LEFT JOIN `products` ON `products`.`id` = `order_products`.`product_id` GROUP BY `orders`.`id`
```

this query is working fine and as I intended to but the problem is when I search by product title example p1

the result I got

```
| id | client |   info  |
-------------------------
| 1  |   c1   |  p1     |
| 2  |   c2   |  p1     |
```

the result I want to get is like this even if the product p2 doesn't appear in search but it's in the order and I am selecting orders not products

```
| id | client | products|
-------------------------
| 1  |   c1   |  p1 p2  |
| 2  |   c2   |  p1     |
```

Answer (score 0):

You want to use a `having` clause, not a `where` clause:

```
SELECT o.*, GROUP_CONCAT(p.title SEPARATOR ' ') AS products
FROM orders o JOIN
     order_products op
     ON op.order_id = o.id JOIN
     products p
     ON p.id = op.product_id
GROUP BY o.id
HAVING SUM( p.title LIKE ? ) > 0;
```

The `?` is a parameter placeholder for what you are looking for.

This returns all products for orders that contain the product you are interested in.

Note the other changes I made to the query:

- I introduced table aliases, so the query is easier to write and to read.
- I removed the backticks, for the same reason.
- I changed the `LEFT JOIN` to `JOIN` because an outer join is not necessary.  Your logic requires at least one match to a product.

Comment: thanks for your answer
my query is really more complicated i search by client name and a lot of other joins is there a way with where clause not having ?